# ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 1) are incompatible when training an object detection algorithm in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

So I am training a program which classifies an image into one of 3 categories which uses ConvNext as a backbone. However, when I try to train the model, I get the error message that the output shapes are incompatible.
Following is the code I wrote:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  "datasetpath",
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  color_mode='rgb',
  seed=120,
  image_size=(2294, 1914),
  batch_size=2
)
model=tf.keras.applications.convnext.ConvNeXtSmall(
    model_name='convnext_small',
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(2294,1914,3),
    classifier_activation='softmax'
)   
output= tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model.layers[-1].output)
output=tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()(output)
output=tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,kernel_initializer='random_uniform')(output)

newModel=keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=output,name='ConvNext')
newModel.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    metrics=[
        metrics.AUC(),
        metrics.Accuracy(),
        metrics.Precision()
    ]
)
history=newModel.fit(
    train_ds,
    epochs=10,
    steps_per_epoch=2081
)
```

I have tried changing the loss function, double checked the image directory and even checked the model summary which gives 3 output numbers corresponding to the probabilities of the 3 classes, however I am unable to understand why the model is expecting only 1 number.

Comment: Looking alright so far, at least from the model side. Did you look if your labels from your dataset are okay? Right no they are inferred from the folder structure of the data.